# Pattern matching for equality

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

```
parserChar :: Char -> Parser Char
parserChar c = Parser ch where
   ch d = case dvChar d of
      Parsed c dp -> Parsed c dp
      _ -> NoParse
```

The above function is supposed to take a Char `c` and return a Parser which will only match `c`. The function `dvChar d` is going to return either `Parsed char dp` or `NoParse` (where `char` is the next character in the string). Thus, I had hoped that `Parsed c dp` would only match a result in which `char==c`, but what's actually happening is that the Parser returned by this function matches *any* character (even though `c` seems to be bound to some particular Char, as a function argument).

The following function works correctly:

```
parserChar :: Char -> Parser Char
parserChar c = Parser ch where
   ch d = case dvChar d of
      Parsed char dp -> if char == c then Parsed char dp else NoParse
      _ -> NoParse
```

Manually coding the parser to parse the letter `'a'` also works correctly, in that

```
case dvChar d of
   Parsed 'a' dp -> Parsed 'a' dp
   _ -> NoParse
```

will only return success if the character was `'a'`.

So what gives? Can you only match literals in a pattern like that (e.g. despite the fact that Char is in class Eq, the `if char==c (..)` still needs to be coded manually), or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: By the way, the "only match constructors" rule is definitely a good thing, because otherwise importing a new top-level definition (say) could greatly change the semantics of a piece of code!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can only match literals. In fact, a better way to think about it is that you can only match constructors, and it so happens that Int, Char, String & co. all have literal constructors.

Note that you can also mix case and guards and write it as (from memory):

```
parserChar :: Char -> Parser Char
parserChar c = Parser ch where
   ch d = case dvChar d of
      Parsed char dp | char == c -> Parsed char dp
      _ -> NoParse
```